# for comprehension from flatMap and future to future

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

I would like something like runProgram2 but currently that part does not compile.  Is there a way to write it somewhat like runProgram2 but so it compiles..

```
package transformer

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Promise, Future}
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object TestingForComprehensions2 {

    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
      val future1: Future[String] = runMyProgram()
      future1.onSuccess {
        case r:String =>       System.out.println("result="+r)
      }


      val future2: Future[String] = runMyProgram2()
      future2.onSuccess {
        case r:String =>       System.out.println("result="+r)
      }

      System.out.println("waiting")
      Thread.sleep(600000)
    }

    def runMyProgram() : Future[String] = {
      val future = serviceCall()
      val middle = serviceCallWrap(future)
      val future2 = middle.flatMap(serviceCall2)
      val future3 = future2.map(processAllReturnCodes)
      future3
    }

    def runMyProgram2() : Future[String] = {
      for {
        result1 <- serviceCall()
        middle = serviceCallWrap(result1)
        result2 <-  serviceCall2(middle)
      } yield processAllReturnCodes(result2)
    }

    def processAllReturnCodes(theMsg: String) : String = {
      "dean"+theMsg
    }

    def serviceCall() : Future[Int] = {
      val promise = Promise.successful(5)
      promise.future
    }

    def serviceCallWrap(f:Future[Int]) : Future[Int] = {
      f
    }

    def serviceCall2(count:Int) : Future[String] = {
      val promise = Promise.successful("hithere"+count)
      promise.future
    }

}
```

Comment: can you provide the compiler error?

Comment: well, the issue is serviceCallWrap takes a Future not an Int which is the normal way so I get a type conversion error of found Int but required Future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serviceCallWrap` expects a future, but you are passing an `Int`, first step would be to remove the `result1 <- serviceCall()` part and call directly `middle = serviceCallWrap(serviceCall())`.

Now `middle` is a future but `serviceCall2` takes an `Int`, in this case you can extract the value from the future using `middle <- serviceCallWrap(serviceCall())`, all together:

```
def runMyProgram2() : Future[String] = {
  for {
    middle <- serviceCallWrap(serviceCall())
    result2 <-  serviceCall2(middle)
  } yield processAllReturnCodes(result2)
}
```

If you want to keep the comprehension structure:

```
def runMyProgram2() : Future[String] = {
  for {
    result1 <- serviceCall()
    middle <- serviceCallWrap(Future(result1))
    result2 <-  serviceCall2(middle)
  } yield processAllReturnCodes(result2)
}
```

The only thing you can't keep (AFAIK) is the assignment expression for `middle`, if you want to keep that you need to change `serviceCall2` signature. This approach though has exactly the same result as the first approach, it's only more verbose.

Comment: it was a trimmed down example and I would prefer serviceCallWrap on the next line.

Comment: It's hard to see how it is gonna be useful from your example though, the result would be the same.

Comment: yes, it was mostly an understanding thing and the method call was a bit bigger so chaining was ugly.  In the end, I changed serviceCall to proxyServiceCall to clean it up though in some cases if I am passing too many things in, that gets ugly too so I like knowing how to do it...thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this figured out now.  or at least this compiles so I can do it on a different line.....

```
def runMyProgram2() : Future[String] = {
  for {
    result1 <- serviceCall()
    middle <- serviceCallWrap(Promise.successful(result1).future)
    result2 <-  serviceCall2(middle)
  } yield processAllReturnCodes(result2)
}
```